# strftime format support two letter day option

Tags: formatting

We use a date format that appends the day at the end of the date like so: `20180109tu@1730`. Is there any way to get the two letter day format?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a C function, not Vi/Vim.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the placing-on-hold of this question. Whilst Vim's `strftime()` function may only be a thin wrapper around the C function, it still *is* a Vim function. Furthermore, it's certainly possible to answer the question using Vim alone: the OP has done so!

Comment: Seems pedantic but whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to make work-around where I just manually go back a few characters and reformat accordingly.

```
nnoremap <leader>d "=strftime("%Y%m%d%a")<CR>Pxh~
nnoremap <leader>D "=strftime("%Y%m%d%a@%H%M%S")<CR>PF@hxhh~E
```